# Creating a field for Email Address in Employee table where Email Address Type is Work, if Null then Personal Email

Tags: sql

I have a table with Active Employees, I need to bring in their email address from the Email table. Some employees have two Email records (Work and Personal). I want to bring in the Work Email and if Null, then bring in the Personal Email, all in one column.

I've tried creating two columns, one for Work and one for Personal, and then a Case Statement to create a new column, but you can't reference a alias in the same query.

I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm not sure if a CTE or Temp table or something else is my answer, but I've been spinning my wheels. (This would be simple for me in Excel with a vlookup, nested in an if/then statement)

[image: Table 1 - Employee]

[image: Table 2 - Email Address]

[image: Desired Results]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for doing this, using conditional aggregation and `coalesce()`:

```
select empid,
       coalesce(max(case when emailtype = 'W' then email end),
                max(case when emailtype = 'P' then email end),
                max(email)
               ) as preferred_email
from emailaddress
group by empid;
```

I should point out that conditional aggregation with `coalesce()` is a bit of a trick.  Here are two more conventional methods:

```
select ea.*
from (select ea.*,
             row_number() over (partition by empid order by emailtype desc) as seqnum
      from emailaddress ea
     ) ea
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, assuming that there is at most one email per type per employee:

```
select ea.*
from emailaddress ea
where ea.emailtype = 'W'
union all
select ea.*
from emailaddress ea
where ea.emailtype = 'H' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from emailaddress ea2
                  where ea2.empid = ea.empid and
                        ea2.emailtype = 'W'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked! I looked at the coalesce, but would have never got this